# Provider-hosted apps - options to create

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

Just for self learning purpose, I want to create few provider-hosted apps, but I don't have any subscription for windows azure service.

I have only trial subscription of office 365.

My question is can I create provider hosted apps without any subscription for azure service (with the help of office 365 trial)?

Is there any free trial available to develop this, which doesn't need any credit card?

Since this is very important for me can any one experienced same situation reply to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Provider Hosted app without deploying it to azure. In your case the app needs to be deployed to on-premise environment. Remember to Select the option "*Use a client secret*" for authenticating the app.

Comment: Hello Nadeem, can you please send link for proper documentation to implement Provider Hosted app in your way? It should be easy to understand and follow.

Comment: Try this link http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-app-event-receivers.html. However, keep in mind that in this case PS 2013 on premise is used and hence certificates are used. You need to give reference to your O365 site and use client secret for authentication as mentioned before.

Comment: Can I use ACS or I can configure a High Trust App?

Comment: I think you have recommended for high trust apps only? am i correct? i have a doubt here? Does ACS option always means windows azure service and a low trust?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following links, it may help you

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx

[2] http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/24/sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-walkthrough-part-1-preparation.aspx